# Design sort column in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want design sort column something like below.

```
create table v_test
(
    id int primary key,
    name nvarchar(50),
    parent_id int, 
    sort int
)    

insert into v_test (id, name, parent_id, sort)
    select 1, 'A1', 0, 1 union all
    select 2, 'A2', 0, 2 union all
    select 3, 'A3', 0, 3 union all
    select 4, 'A4', 0, 4 union all
    select 5, 'A5', 0, 5 union all
    select 6, 'A1', 1, 1 union all
    select 7, 'A2', 1, 2 union all
    select 8, 'A3', 1, 3 union all
    select 9, 'A4', 1, 4 union all
    select 10, 'A5', 1, 5 

select * 
from v_test 
where parent_id = 1 
order by sort
```

Now with `parent_id = 1`, how can I update sort column without updating other values?

For example: when I update column `Id = 7` to 5, I must update all other columns like this.

```
update v_test 
set sort = 5 
where id = 7
-- I must update other column
update  v_test set sort = 2 where id = 8
update  v_test set sort = 3 where id = 9
update  v_test set sort = 4 where id = 10
```

How can I design sort column in database without having to updating all other column values?

Comment: Leave gaps between your sort values i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40 then when you want to move 40 to second place set it to 15. Of course thats more complex because you have to check there is space.

Comment: or just use a float column or hierarchy id rather than integers